# Updating togglebutton cheched state gives error

Tags: android, xamarin, togglebutton, checked

i have this ToggleButton

```
  <ToggleButton
   android:id="@+id/PlaymusicToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/mediabutton"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/b_st"  /> //currently pressed turning the toggle on
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/b_st" /> //currently pressed turning the toggle off
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/b_st" /> //not pressed default checked state
<item android:drawable="@drawable/b_pl" /> //default non-pressed non-checked
```

and im trying to update the checked value from a function

```
    private void UpdatePlayer(int _music){


        if (_music== 0) 
        {
            music.Playing = true;
            //playmusicToggleButton.RequestLayout ();
            playmusicToggleButton.Checked = true;
```

but im getting this strange error

```
  [ResourceType] No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x000000
```

and the rest of the UpdatePlayer doesn't load, what is this error about?

I have defined togglebutton on the beggining of the fragment

```
  public class ControlPanel : ListFragment, SeekBar.IOnSeekBarChangeListener
  {
    ToggleButton playmusicToggleButton;
```

and im assigned it with a value on OnCreateView

```
playmusicToggleButton = view.FindViewById<ToggleButton> (Resource.Id.PlaymusicToggleButton);
```

Comment: where have you defined playmusicToggleButton?

Comment: i have just try with:

playmusicToggleButton = (ToggleButton) View.FindViewById<ToggleButton> (Resource.Id.playmusicToggleButton);
    playmusicToggleButton.Checked = true;

on my function and i get the same error.

Comment: what is this R? im using Xamarin, im not using java (eclipse or android studio)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72445/discussion-between-cdrosos-and-semicolon).

Comment: I see, I did not see Xamarin in tags, my bad. but from Xamarin point of view,  nothing wrong with your playmusicToggleButton = view.FindViewById<ToggleButton> (Resource.Id.PlaymusicToggleButton);

Comment: is it possible to has something to do with the xml?

Comment: definitely. These errors mostly come along due to xml stuffs. Make sure you have all drawable resources you put in your xml. Also check if extension is .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing like this:

```
playmusicToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.playmusicToggleButton);              
playmusicToggleButton.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: my error was on somewhere elase, thanks and sorry stackoverflow community for being so nooby